# Search tables and columns in stored procedure in all databases

Tags: sql-server, object, search, stored-procedures

I have an Excel list with object name and column name (like so..)

| Object Name | Column Name |
| --- | --- |
| OBJECT1 | Column A |
| OBJECT2 | Column C |

And I want to know if there's a way to search for all the object names and/or column names at once  from the list to see if they exist in any stored procedure in all databases in SQL Server. I know I can use the SQL Search utility to search but it can only search one object at a time.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't re-invent the wheel, there are many existing scripts out there, like [this one](https://sqlblog.org/2021/10/20/a-handy-search-procedure).

Comment: Look up `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` and `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`

Comment: Need to provide some code/fuctions used to try out so far. And info on what works and what not. Also the referenced used.